# Javascript issue on magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am facing that is slider images on my site does not appear on the first attempt and I get the following error but when I refresh page sliders appears

Uncaught TypeError: `$(...).swMegamenu` is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: `$(...).owlCarousel` is not a function
collapsible.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function

Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Please share your code, where you have called that `swMegamenu`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use always require js to call custom js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    Your Code ....
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend adding all JS to JS files rather than inside templates with a `script` tag.